# EC2 Windows - Can I use ephemeral storage as root?

Tags: windows-server-2012, amazon-ec2

Can I use ephemeral storage as the root of my windows instances?

I have a auto scaling group with windows instances and I was thinking if I could use the ephemeral storage as root. I'll never turn my instaces off. They will be shutdown when I don't need them and new instances will be created when I need.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should be able to do this. If you create an AMI with your setup, you could create an instance on ephemeral storage of it.

I have done this with Linux instances, and I don't see why Windows instances should differ.

Comment: I have tried to create an instance with ephemeral storage as root but I could not configure this way. Do you have any tutorial on how to do it?